# Named range supposed to be updated from the source column values or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I understand one of the purposes of named range is to create a new range that will derive its elements from the source column. So when there is any revision in the source column, that should reflect in the named range.

For instance, I have created a named range tickerrange that derives its elements from Ticker Symbol column.

If I delete elements in Ticker Symbol column, I find such deletion not reflected in the tickerrange.

Kindly help me know what is the logic behind creating named range and are their elements not supposed to be updated from the source column.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make changes to the source, there are not immediately reflected on the pivottable. You need to refresh to get the latest data. Right-clicon a cell of the pivottable, then select Refresh. This can also be accomplished from the ribbon by selecting a cell of the pivottable, then PivotTable Analyze -> Refresh (or Refresh All if you have other data sources you also want to update).

If you want the change to be reflected automatically, you can create a macro (macros can be created with the desktop version of Excel, not the online version). Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Find the the source sheet on the Project Explorer (on the left side), double-click on it. Enter the following code:

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

The macro will trigger when you make changes to the source data and reflect them to the pivottable immediately.

Comment: Yes, refresh updates.